# npm start command open specific page at running

Tags: npm, react-scripts

I m developping a reactjs app.

So to start the server I run :

```
react-scripts start
```

However this opens http://localhost:3000 in my browser.

Is there a manner to change the url to http://localhost:3000/login ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
PUBLIC_URL=\"http://localhost:3000/login\" react-scripts start
```